# How to get DoctrineExtensions sluggable working with doctrine 2.3 / symfony 3.4?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4, doctrine-extensions

I try to get sluggable doctrine extention working on my project. I follow a setup step found on Internet, bu it seems to not working (@Gedmo\Slug seems to be not called/triggered).

The purpuse is to slug a post title.

I'm using Symfony 3.4 and Doctrine 2.3 on PHP 7.1.

Is someone know how to get this work, i would be grateful.

I added the bundle in AppKernel (`new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle()`)

Here is my other project files :

## composer.json

```
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.6.4",
        "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
        "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "^1.3.0",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.3.4"
    },
```

## app/config/config.yml

```
# Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle configuration
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            sluggable: true
```

## src/xxx/xxxBundle/Entity/Advert.php

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Advert
{


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"title"})
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, unique=true, nullable=true)
 */
private $slug;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figure out !

I forgot to add the service in my bundle.

So in my services.yml, i add this lines :

```
gedmo.listener.sluggable:
    class: Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: pgsql }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]
```